# How do I separately bake lightmaps for different objects in a scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

Suppose I have a scene with two discrete states:

DAY: the sun shines on a cube at the origin

NIGHT: the moon shines on a cylinder at the origin

All the aforementioned objects (sun, moon, cube, cylinder) are static; the day/night transition consists solely of selectively enabling and disabling them. Is it possible to bake lightmaps for the cube and cylinder separately, so they'd look as they would if day and night were two separate scenes? If so, how?

Comment: Hello, to do so you can edit the settings in the "lightmap" tap. Click on Window>lighting and there in Object. Add as many objects as you wish and edit the lighting there. You can learn more about the different techniques [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html) and [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/graphics/lighting-and-rendering). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but unless I've missed something, that doesn't quite answer my question. At least, not in the affirmative. I see plenty of options for modifying how individual objects are baked, but the bake itself is still a scenewide thing, and the resulting lightmap is associated with the scene as a whole rather than its constituent objects.

That is to say, in my example I wouldn't be able to bake the cube's map, change the scene, then bake the cylinder's. If I want them to be in the same scene, I'd have to bake them together. Unless I've missed something.

Comment: yes, I understand your concern. I am not a Unity Master but I am going to try explain it to you. The lightmaps are for non-directional lights. In games the Sun/Moon are (usually) directional to simplify things. However, if you want to bake the lights that means that you aren't going to cast shadows of dynamic bodies. That said you can use the GI lights to accomplish that and the light array to set it to each object. Sorry if I didn't answer you accurately.